# std::thread run time error "Enable multithreading to use std::thread: Operation not permitted"

Tags: gcc

I am trying to port a program that was running without any problem when the environment set up was
Ubuntu 12.0
QTCreator Version - 2.4.1
QT - 4.8.0
gcc - 4.6.3 to a new environment

Ubuntu 14.04
QTCreator Version - 3.0.1
QT - 5.2.1
gcc - 4.8

Unfortunately I end up seeing a runtime error "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error' what(): Enable multithreading to use std::thread:Operation not permitted"

As per my understanding this seems to be an issue with compiler compatibility. Either I miss some options during compilations or a bug from compiler.

How to get his fixed? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: **std::thread** was introduced with **C++11**. Are you compiling with that standard? Also this question belongs to **Stack Overflow**.

Comment: @potAito: Not compiling with C++11 and not linking to pthread would both give compilation errors, not runtime exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

gcc 4.8 had [a bug related to this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-defaults/+bug/1228201). You could try the workaround mentioned in the bug report: Add the flags

```
-Wl,--no-as-needed
```

to the compilation.